# MVC5 - ViewData.ModelMetadata.Properties is empty

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5, entity-framework-6

I'm trying to iterate over model's properties and print display names -

```
@foreach (var property in ViewData.ModelMetadata.Properties) 
{
<th>
    <a href="@MyClass.GetSortableUrlString(property.DisplayName)">property.DisplayName</a>
</th>
}
```

But the control never gets into the loop because `ViewData.ModelMetadata.Properties` is always empty.

Also tried `@foreach (var property in Model.GetType().GetProperties())` but the same problem here, there are no properties.

The model is an IEnumerable of an EF6 entity object (autogenerated object via database first approach on a sql server database) -

```
@model IEnumerable<MyProject.DataAccess.Models.Table1>
```

I realize that the codes above seem to be trying to get DisplayNames of an IEnumerable and maybe that's the problem but I don't know how to change `ViewData.ModelMetadata.Properties`so that it works off the object contained in the collection (`ViewData.First().ModelMetadata.Properties` doesn't work either)

Note: As you see, all that I'm really trying to do is to turn DisplayNames into sortable links, so I don't care how the iteration happens as long as it does happen but it'll be nice to be able to retrieve DisplayNames instead of property names. Also tried overriding Html.DisplayNameFor but that's probably a different question.